# How to sum with specific range of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table

```
tax  number  yearmonth(int)
100   45    202105
2     45    202104  
35    45    202102
47    45    202012
58    45    202005
```

I try to aggregate sum for every number by last 12 month
For instance 202105 - I need sum month between (202012 - 202001)
Main problem ->  not every number has all 12 months

I tried over clause but it sums all 12 preceding records. It does not take into account missing year records.

```
case when yearmonth-lag(yearmonth,1) OVER ( order by  number, yearmonth) <> (0) then
    sum([tax])  OVER (
     PARTITION BY [number]
       ORDER BY yearmonth
     Rows BETWEEN  11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) end
```

Comment: Use a cte to generate start to end months. Outer join.

Comment: can you add desired output ?

Comment: This is where it's useful having a *calendar table* to hand.

Comment: You are pretty close to your solution. Check out how to generate the missing months here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299401/fill-in-missing-periods-in-between-periods-where-missing-transactions, and use the windowing function to calculate the 12 month sum.

Comment: Last 12 months is the same than " > yearmonth - 100". Maybe you can explore that way...